# What is the best way to use enrich-my-library in scala?

Tags: scala, enrich-my-library

The are two different way to implement it.

One is more short

```
implicit def toR1(s:String) = new { def getLength = s.length)}
```

Second is more long

```
class R2(s:String){def getLength2 = s.length)}
implicit def toR2(s:String) = new R2(s)
```

Which one is better?

Comment: `implicit class R3(s:String) { def getLength = s.length }` :) I really hope that it will be included in Scala 2.10: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/implicit-classes.html

Comment: a possible duplicate: [How to implement intermediate types for implicit methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220359/how-to-implement-intermediate-types-for-implicit-methods/5220725). TL;DR the second is better performance-wise as the first way uses reflection under the hood

Comment: implicit classes _are_ included in Scala 2.10, so perhaps the currently only answer to this question is obsolete.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first version uses a [structural type](http://java.dzone.com/articles/duck-typing-scala-structural). It makes it possible to write short and readable code, but a disadvantage of structural types is that reflection is used at runtime when you call the method in the structural type. Calling a method via reflection is slower than calling a method directly.

More details are in this blog post (written by me): [Avoid structural types when pimping libraries](http://www.scala-notes.org/2010/06/avoid-structural-types-when-pimping-libraries/)